# Where is it written that Thirumalisai Alwar knows the Vedas?

Tags: sri-vaishnava, alwar

[This](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/35030/what-is-the-meaning-of-the-verse-which-tirumazhisai-alwar-reminded-to-the-brahmi) question says that Thirumalisai Alwar (who is a non-dvija) knows the Vedas and even assisted some Brahmins in picking up where they left off in the Vedic recitation.

My question is, where is this story from? Like is it from the divya prabandhams or writings of an acharya?